# Github ssh key added, checked, still doesn't work

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I created ssh key as per this [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

Assigned it to the ssh-agent.

Added it to the github account as per this [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

```
ssh-add -l -E md5
```

Shows correct footprint

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Says:

```
Hi <My username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But still:

```
git push
```

Asks for:

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Check out this: [switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh)

High are the changes that you clone your repo over HTTPS and now want to push using SSH.

As suggested on the [GitHub site](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) check your remote origin by doing this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

In case you have `https...` change it to `ssh` by doing something like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: Beware of the trailing `.git` !